# Why does PHP returns a character with the string i echoed in ajax success function

Tags: php, ajax

Previously, i was using PHP 5.6.3 with sqlsrv on IIS 7.5 on windows 7 and PHP was working fine with ajax success. I upgraded to Windows 10 and when i try to echo a string, a character is found attached to the string in ajax function. Please I want to know what is causing that.

PHP

```
    $params=array($_POST['uID']);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE uID=?";
    $stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$params);
    if(!$stmt)
    {
      echo "1"; 
    }
    else
    {
        $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
        if($row>0)
        {
           echo "1";
        }
        else
        {
           echo "0";
        }
    }
```

AJAX

```
    var uID=$('#fUID').val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        url:"adminDB.php",
        data:"uID="+uID+"&action="+action,
        cache:true,
        success:function(msg)
        {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: How about a hexdump of that output instead of a screenshot?

Comment: thanks for the edit

Comment: instead of an alert, log the message like this: console.log('response', msg); - and see what pops up in the console

Comment: Please i did the console log and the response is 0 but the problem is if i try  to compare the msg==0 it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

My guess will be that your `adminDB.php` file contains [BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702522/utf-8-bom-and-headers-in-php) at the beginning of the file.
If you will remove that from your PHP file (you can do this using [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.9.2.html) and some other text editors) you will be able to compare the strings the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the header to output json, since that's what jquery's ajax function expects by default:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

You should do this before your `echo` statements.

Comment: Please Sir, I am suspecting the problem may come from the PHP Configuration but have no ideas where to go and make that changes

Answer (score 0):

After wondering my head over this issue...i finally got a way around it. I used json_encode() and was able to compare the string returned. I definitely know the problem is an issue between PHP and SQLSRV drivers in Windows 10 32bit.

```
$resp=array('message'=>'1');
echo json_encode($resp);
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't think of that - yes echo json_encode was the missing piece.